# contenteditable not working in safari but works in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, safari, contenteditable

I'm having a strange issue...

This works in chrome as expected but in safari it only gets .. glowing but doesn't react on key input..

this is the method that fires the text edition:

```
var namebloc = $(event.currentTarget).find('.column_filename');
var oldvalue = namebloc.html();

namebloc.attr('contentEditable', true).focus();
document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null);

namebloc.blur(function() 
    {
    $(this).attr('contentEditable', false).unbind( "keydown" ).unbind( "blur" );
    var newvalue = $(this).html().replace('"','&quot;').replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
    console.log(newvalue);
    });
namebloc.keydown(function(e)
    {
    if(e.keyCode==27){ $(this).html(oldvalue);}//escape
    if(e.keyCode==13){  $(this).blur(); }//enter    
    });
```

This is a screenshot in chrome when fired this works as expected... [image]

and this is the result in safari.. no reaction to keyboard or mouse selection:
[image]

Any idea why and how to solve this in safari?

this is the HTML before the method is called :

```
<span field="filename" class="column_filename" style="width:763px;">eiffel (2).JPG</span>
```

This is when it's called (at the same time as screenshots)

```
<span field="filename" class="column_filename" style="width:763px;" contenteditable="true">eiffel (2).JPG</span>
```

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Safari has the `user-select` CSS setting as `none` by default.
You can use:

```
[contenteditable] {
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    user-select: text;
}
```

To make it work.

Comment: This actually answers the question and it saved me a whole evening of despair... feeling bad I can't give you more than one upvote!

Comment: Thank you! Many users of ckeditor would find this helpful

Comment: Still relevant in 2017, and Safari 10.1.1. Thanks a lot for the solution

Comment: ... and in Safari 11

Comment: just found out about your answer, picked it as the right answer

Comment: I cannot deselect an element clicking out of it. Only if I click an input (testing on an iPod)

Comment: Still relevant in 2018 on Safari 11.x .. What the heck ?!

Comment: Safari is the new IE. I get convinced about it over and over. Thanks for the answer, a time saver!

Comment: Still relevant in 2021 on Safari 13.1.3

Comment: thank, it's work good in safari

Comment: Still relevant in 2022 Safari 15.3. While porting my Extension to Safari i wasted and entire day figuring out what is wrong with contenteditable. Your answer saved me N number of days of despair. Thank you so much. @wOxxOm to notice this.

Answer (score 3):

In Safari, despite also being WebKit based, there is differing behavior when clicking on an element that has the `user-select` property set. Chrome seems to key-off that css property and prevent any focus going to the element that was clicked (thanks for continuing to develop a modern and sensible browser Google), while Safari does nothing with that css property regarding focus, and sets focus on the clicked element anyway.

One solution in Safari is to use a proper html button element, but this sucks from a styling perspective.

A better solution is to trap the mousedown event (the first to fire of the Mouse type events in a click), and `preventDefault()` on the event. This should work in any version of Safari.

For example

```html
<span onclick="document.execCommand('bold', false);" onmousedown="event.preventDefault();">
  <i class="material-icons">format_bold</i>
</span>
```