# Safari contenteditable div focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I click to a contenteditable div, on focus the vertical line that indicates that I can write, disapears. I have to click twice to make it visible and be able to write.

This only fails if:
- Safari (last versions 12.0. I could not check older versions)
- contenteditable div (it works well in a form)
- on focus
- only if the user cliks on the text. It works well if the user clicks on the div but outside the text.

I simplified so much the case to find the problem. I do not know what else to try.
- Is that just a bug in Safari?
- Any idea how to make it work well?

```js
$(function(){
    
 $(".text").focus(function () {
  if ( ($(this).text() == "one thing") ) {
   $(this).text("");
  }
 });

 $(".text").blur(function () {
  if ($(this).text() == "") { 
   $(this).text("one thing");
  }
 });

})
```

```css
.text {
 width: 50%;
 padding: 6px 10px;
 background-color: whiteSmoke;
 outline:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text" contenteditable="true">one thing</div>
```

Comment: I just tested on Safari Version 11.0.3 and it's working perfectly

Comment: @Enzo: I tried again and in my computer and Safari 12 if I do one click I am unable to write. I need two clicks

Answer (score 3):

Try this solution posted in the past:

Safari has the user-select CSS setting as none by default. You can use:

```
[contenteditable] {
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    user-select: text;
}
```

Source: [contenteditable not working in safari but works in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20435166/contenteditable-not-working-in-safari-but-works-in-chrome)

Comment: I added your code to the css and I see no difference: http://jsfiddle.net/L7rp56x9/

Answer (score 0):

To add to this solution already given, which is correct, you need to replace the [contenteditable] with the class selector in your css file. So whichever element is contenteditable you would place that there. For example:

```
.content-to-edit-fake-class-name {
-webkit-user-select: text;
user-select: text;
}
```